# Diagonalization of a matrix ${}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

When we do Diagonalization of a matrix, what does it mean when 1 of the condition is that the characteristic polynomial has to 'split'? Let's say i calculate the determinant with lambda, what do i have to look for so the characteristic polynomial split? does it have to do with the degree of the found polynomial?

Comment: What do you mean by "split."  $\det (A-\lambda I) =  p(\lambda)= 0$  The degree of this polynomial equals the number of rows in $A$ and the number of roots (including complex roots and multiplicities) must equal the degree of the polynomial.

Comment: I have this definition in the book but it's too weird to me:

' A polynomial f (t) in P(F) splits over F if there are scalars c , a1 , . . . , an (not necessarily distinct) in F such that
f (t) = c(t − a1)(t − a2) . . . (t − an). '' 

So if a matrice has 4 rows then polynomial must be something along ^3? and if i have 2 values for lambda I'd need for example 2 multiplicity for each or 3 for one 1 for the other? Thank you by the way.

Comment: That is the abstract algebra definition of splinting or in more simple terms factorizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A polynomial splits if it can written as a product of linear factors. That is, $p(x) = a_n x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1x + a_0$ splits iff there exists $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ such that

$$
p(x) = a_n(x - \lambda_1) (x-\lambda_2) \cdots (x - \lambda_n).
$$

The polynomial $x^2 - 1$ splits since $x^2 - 1 = (x-1)(x+1)$. Does the polynomial $x^2 + 1$ split? It depends. If we're in the real numbers, then no it doesn't. However, if we allow ourselves to use *complex numbers*, then it does: $x^2 +1 = (x+i)(x-i)$.

So the question of whether a polynomial splits depends over which field you take your numbers to be in. The complex numbers have a special property called [algebraic closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraically_closed_field) which means that every complex-valued polynomial splits over $\Bbb C$. (This is the so-called [Fundamental theorem of Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraically_closed_field).) The real numbers do not have this property, as the example $x^2 + 1$ demonstates.

A real polynomial *can* be factored down into a product of quadratic and linear polynomials, however: $p(x) = q_1(x) \cdots q_n(x)$. Once you have done this, if any of the quadratic polynomial, $q_k$ has no real roots, then you can conclude $p$ does not split over $\Bbb R$. If it factors down to linear terms, then definitionally it splits.

Comment: Thank you very much, i appreciate it!